# http post in angularJS cross domain to asp.mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I've seen other posts like this but nothing fixed my problem. My http get function works great, So I can pull data from my asp.net server to my angular server. I cannot get the http post function to work. When I run this angular code on the same server as my asp.net application, It works great. When I run it from my ionic/angular server it passes null object.

Here is my ionic/angular code.

```
$scope.SendData = function(events){     

   var AppdataObj = {
            artist            : events.artist,
            ticketPrice       : events.price,
            ticketsAvailable  : events.tickets,
            date              : events.date
    }; 
    var NewAppData = JSON.stringify(AppdataObj);
    var config = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}

$http.post('http://localhost:50384/EventsInformation/APPMethod',NewAppData,
config)
        .success(function(NewAppData) {
            alert('Successfully Added Event '+ NewAppData);
        })
        .error(function(NewAppData) {
            alert('Error while Adding Event ' + NewAppData);
        });  

    }; //  end SendData function
```

I don't know if I'm handling my JSON object correctly in my asp.net controller.
I put a breakpoint right after the method gets called to see what is passed to NewAppData. from here I want to add it to my EventsList table in my database

```
 public JsonResult APPMethod(EventsDetails NewAppData)
    {

        return Json(new {status = "Event Added Successfully" });
    }
```

EventsDetails is my model

```
    [Key]
    public int EventsDetailsId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must Enter An Artist")]
    public string artist { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must Enter A Ticket Price")]
    public decimal ticketPrice { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must Ticket Quantity Available")]
    public int ticketsAvailable { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must Enter The Date")]
    public string date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try to include the attribute [HttpPost] in your action.
You can also change your method to be: public JsonResult APPMethod([FromBody]EventsDetails NewAppData)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. same result